# Mercurial: Adding changes after specific changeset in a branch and merging it

Tags: merge, mercurial, branch

Let me first explain the situation.
A while ago I had master and feature branch. Then after master branch was built and sent to production, I've merged feature branch with master one. So I have only master branch now. A lot of commits later, I receive request to add fix/feature to code which is in production. So I've located specific changeset which is before merge with feature branch, and I would need to add certain code to it but staying still in master branch.

Current situation:

```
master   --1-------o--P--X----2--o--o--o--*
            \                /
feature      o--o--o--o--o--o
```

Changeset P is the one which is in production, and X is desired place where I need to add the fix and push again to production. After that, I need my tip to contain everything + X.

So in master branch I would have to have:

- all things before merge with feature branch
- fix

With this repository state, we can push build to production. After this is done, I need to add all the changes that were made up to today and merge with this new changes, so that as a result I have:

- all things before merge with feature branch
- changes after merge with feature branch
- fix

Now I can continue working with all the changes.

I use Mercurial, but I'm not so savvy in it.

I would welcome any insight or help.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved this problem for me was:

1. Revert to revision before feature branch was implemented (to P changeset) and commited it
2. Added fix and commited it
3. Used backout to take out revert from step 1
4. Merged changes and commited

So after step 2, I had all the code which was in production + fix. Then I used step 3 to get back to the state that I had originally, and merged changeset with fix to it. So in the end I have all the code with feature + fix.

Answer (score 0):

If I've got this right, the first part of what you want is represented in this diagram:

```
release-2 --------F'
                 /
master  --o--o--P--o--m--o--o--tip
                     /
                    /
feature --o--F--o--o
```

where P is the changeset used for production, F is the feature you wish to port to the production release, and m is the merge of the branches.

Porting a changeset in this way is called cherry picking. A way of doing that is:

1. hg up P               # use changeset for P
2. hg branch release-2   # optional, otherwise master will have 2 heads
3. hg graft -r F         # use changeset for F

And F' is then your new production release (after testing of course).

I didn't understand the second part of your question where you apparently want to port stuff onto F'. Why not just carry on working from the current tip? Your next release would be taken as another branch from the master at some changeset in the future.

I'd recommend that you experiment with a test repo before doing it for real. [That is true of learning how to use any new hg command.]

Comment: 1. hg branch release-2 -f (if is mandatory, due to existing branch) 2. 2. Don't see *any* sense in hg branch 3. You have some mistake in assumptions: new child have to be added to `<some parent>` of P in master

Comment: I've updated my question with graph to maybe clear things up.

Comment: One assumption I made was that the new feature has already been written and is in the feature branch. That seemed obvious at the time, but maybe now it is ambiguous.

Comment: It is considered good practice to create a branch for released product, at least it is in my commercial world. The advantages are obvious; you can add new changesets to the release branch as necessary as users demand it. But that's not necessary in all environments.

Comment: I've added my solution which worked for me, but thanks for time and ideas!

Answer (score 0):

In plain words:

- Move to needed "injection point" in history
- Make needed changes, commit
- Test new `tip` (somehow)
- (Add fixes, if needed)
- Merge your current `tip` with "old" tip (2-nd head of `master`)

In Mercurial commands

- `hg up X`
- coding here...
- `hg commit -m "description of change"`
- `hg archive PATH/TO/ARCHIVE_FOR_PROD`
- testing here...
- `hg merge` (without `-r`, because you merge two heads in branch)
- `hg resolve` (*if needed* for resolving conflicts, interactive merge will be better choice)
- `hg commit -m "Merge added feature"`

Comment: This solution will work for solving the immediate problem. But, what happens when users ask for feature Y to be added to the original production release? Then Z? The graph will soon get difficult to understand. It's often better to separate releases into their own branches for this eventuality, with features ported between them as necessary using cherry picking techniques.

Comment: @JohnJefferies - I hate... no, **HATE** cherry-pick. "Branch per task"  (named branches) and tagging of "release" changesets (still inside `master` branch) will be OK (for me)

Comment: I said branch per release, not branch per task. As for whether cherry picking is good or not, it all depends on how complex releases get. When we have dozens or hundreds of changesets to port to long-lived releases, branches are a very good thing for us. YMMV [and obviously does].

Comment: I would prefer branches as well, but current state of automatic build was too complex to change so I had to do it in one branch. Thanks for your time and ideas though!